# psfrag package doesn't work in TexMaker

Tags: eps, psfrag

i am writing my report and i had a problem with `psfrag`. it is working with overleaf but it didn't with TexMaker. The picture "solution_conceptv8" is uploaded in the latex file but the words didn't change.
Anyone has an idea about this issue. Thanks.
[image: this picture shows simulation results of "solution_conceptv8"]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color} %%%% adding color package
\usepackage{psfrag} %%%% adding psfrag package
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\myP}{P} 
\newcommand{\myt}{t} % the same for the time
\newcommand{\mytn}{\myt_0} % the same for the time
\newcommand{\chstation}{c} % the same for the time
\newcommand{\n} {N}
\newcommand{\Pev}[2]{\myP_{\text{EV},#1,#2}} %\newcommand{\Pev}{{P}_{\text{EV},c,t}}
\newcommand{\Pl}[1]{\myP_{\text{eL},#1}} %\newcommand{\Pl}{{P}_{\text{eL},t}}
%pv variables
\newcommand{\Ppv}[1]{\myP_{\text{PV},#1}}     %\newcommand{\Ppv}{{P}_{\text{PV},t}}
\newcommand{\Ppvg}[1]{\myP_{\text{PVG},#1}}
\newcommand{\Ppvl}[1]{\myP_{\text{PVL},#1}}
\newcommand{\Ppvev}[1]{\myP_{\text{PVEV},#1}}
\newcommand{\Ppvb}[1]{\myP_{\text{PVB},#1}}
%chp variables
\newcommand{\Pchp}[1]{\myP_{\text{eCHP},#1}}  %\newcommand{\Pchp}{{P}_{\text{eCHP},t}}
\newcommand{\Pchpg}[1]{\myP_{\text{CHPG},#1}}
\newcommand{\Pchpl}[1]{\myP_{\text{CHPL},#1}}
\newcommand{\Pchpev}[1]{\myP_{\text{CHPEV},#1}}
\newcommand{\Pchpb}[1]{\myP_{\text{CHPB},#1}}
%battery variables
\newcommand{\Pbch}[1]{\myP_{\text{Bch},#1}} %\newcommand{\Pb}{{P}_{\text{B},t}}
\newcommand{\Pbdis}[1]{\myP_{\text{Bdis},#1}}
\newcommand{\Pbl}[1]{\myP_{\text{BL},#1}}
\newcommand{\Pbev}[1]{\myP_{\text{BEV},#1}}
%grid variables
\newcommand{\Pgin}[1]{\myP_{\text{Gin},#1}}
\newcommand{\Pgout}[1]{\myP_{\text{Gout},#1}} %\newcommand{\Pg}{{P}_{\text{G},t}}
\newcommand{\Pgev}[1]{\myP_{\text{GEV},#1}}
\newcommand{\Pgl}[1]{\myP_{\text{GL},#1}}
\begin{document}

\section{Solution concept}
%\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\psfrag{ppv}{$\Ppv{\myt}$}
\psfrag{pb}{$\Pbdis{\myt}$}
\psfrag{pchp}{$\Pchp{\myt}$}
\psfrag{pl}{$\Pl{\myt}$}
\psfrag{pg}{$\Pgout{\myt}$}
\psfrag{pev}{$\Pev{\chstation}{\myt}$}
\hspace{-25mm}\includegraphics[width= 1.3 \textwidth,height=.4\textheight]{solution_conceptv8.eps}
\end{center} 
\caption[solution concept of the EMS]{solution concept of the EMS.}\label{fig: loadprofile }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you make sure to use `latex dvips ps2pdf`, not `pdflatex`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i changed the configuration to `latex dvips ps2pdf` i got this error: `! Undefined control sequence.<recently read> \Pb ...ght=.4\textheight]{solution_conceptv8.eps}`

Comment: well those commands `\P...` are not defined by default and you have not provided any example code that we can run, make sure you have defined them all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i wrote again the whole code in my post above. You can check. I don't know how to upload the eps file here in order that you get everything and run the code.

Comment: Unrelated: all of those `_{\text{...}}` are wrong, use `\mathrm` instead. The contents of `\text` is italic if the font out side of math is italic, which is NOT what you want here.

Comment: Additionally don't use the center env to center images inside figures. It introduces extra vertical space above and below as does the `figure` env (replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`

Comment: We of course cannot say much else about your psfrag stuff as we do not have access to the image

Comment: @daleif i inserted above the result that i got only 3 changed and the others no, also i want to know how to change the size of the label because it is bigger in the picture

Comment: Erh, that is not an eps as the site does not support eps. You'll have to upload that somewhere else and provide a link. BTW: why not draw this directly in latex using tikz? No eps, no psfrac and the font is the same as in the document.

Comment: The posted code does not produce an undefined command error (I changed the image to example-image.eps  so it would run here) please post an example that produces the error that you are asking about. Incidentally do not do  `[width= 1.3 \textwidth,height=.4\textheight]`  just specify width or height, not both or you will distort the image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the same code that i shared i used it and i got the results in the picture above. I can not recognize why `ppv`  `pchp` and  `pev` are not changing and also the size of the others is big even with specify only width or height

Comment: The undefined command error is fixed. The psfrag  manual does explain that it can only replace simple strings if your eps file has the letters individually placed or added as paths not as a font character then it can not replace them.  Impossible to say without seeing the eps

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your comments are usefull and the problem was solved thanks.